# Why is ACL not working as intended in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, acl

I have a directory named `music`. I have set setgid and sticky bit on `music` directory.

```
soubhik@dev:~$ getfacl music/
# file: music/
# owner: soubhik
# group: media
# flags: -st
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
```

After entering the following commands `setfacl -d -m g::rwx music/ ; setfacl -d -m o::--- music/`, this is the status of `music` directory.

```
soubhik@dev:~$ getfacl music/
# file: music/
# owner: soubhik
# group: media
# flags: -st
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::---

soubhik@dev:~$ ls -ld music/
drwxrws--T+ 2 soubhik media 4.0K Jul 22 00:50 music/
```

I created a `new_file` in `music` directory, this is what I get :-

```
-rw-rw---- 1 soubhik media 0 Jul 22 00:56 new_file    #I expected rwxrwx---
```

I expected `rwxrwx---` instead of `rw-rw----`. Where did I go wrong?
The group & owner has `rwx` permission but the files created in directory is getting `rw-`.
Also I don't think `umask` is interfering since its set to `002`

Comment: I believe that the same philosophy as for *umask* applies here: The x bit on files is never set automatically, since x indicates that the file is executable. An empty file can't be executable. However, the x bit on a directory will be set automatically.

Comment: So the only way to automate this task is to make a script, right?

Comment: The only way to automate **any** task is a script.